# How to create a popup view?

Tags: iphone, uipopovercontroller

How to create a pop up view programatically in xcode 4 ?
I am trying to create a popup view which has a webview in it I am adding a back button in the view. I would like to go to the previous view from which it is called when the back button is pressed .
How do I do that ??

Comment: Are you asking about the popover view?

Comment: There is no popover view on the iPhone. If you want to make a modal view, read Apple's modal view guidelines. http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/ModalViewControllers/ModalViewControllers.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007457-CH111-SW1

Comment: Why not to build it yourself?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use this and customize them as u needed

https://github.com/sonsongithub/PopupView

Answer (score 1):

**Step:1 -**  In storyboard create new VC, create new UIView inside VC. name it (ViewPopupUI) and then declare fields and properties you want inside ViewPopupUI.

**Step:2 -** Inside VC

```
@IBOutlet private weak var viewPopupUI:UIView!
@IBOutlet var btnClose: UIButton!
```

> 

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

   self.showViewWithAnimation()
}
```

> 

```
@IBAction func btnCloseAction(_ sender: Any) {

    self.hideViewWithAnimation()
}
```

> 

```
 //MARK: - Animation Method
private func showViewWithAnimation() {

    self.view.alpha = 0
    self.viewPopupUI.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 0.1, y: 0.1)

    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3) {
        self.viewPopupUI.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 1.0, y: 1.0)
        self.view.alpha = 1
    }
}

private func hideViewWithAnimation() {

    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3, animations: {

        self.viewPopupUI.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 0.1, y: 0.1)
        self.view.alpha = 0

    }, completion: {
        (value: Bool) in

        self.removeFromParent()
        self.view.removeFromSuperview()
    })
}
```

> Call popup

```
let popupVC = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "SchoolEventGoingPopup_VC") as! SchoolEventGoingPopup_VC
    popupVC.strId =  self.dictEventDetails?.object(forKey: "id") as? Int
    view.addSubview(popupVC.view)
    addChildViewController(popupVC)
```